# NSTextField Subclass Crashes on setLineBreakMode: method

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, crash, nstextfield

I have a subclass of NSTextField and I setting the LineBreakMode.

It works fine under my mac with Yosemite 
and Crashes for one of my users on Mavericks

`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[XTextField setLineBreakMode:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fc784548ad0'`

How could I work this round ?

Header File of the subclass

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface XTextField : NSTextField

- (void)setText:(NSString *)text

@end
```

Implementation

```
#import "XTextField.h"
@implementation XTextField

- (void)setText:(NSString *)text
{
    if (text)
    {
        [self setStringValue:text];
    }
    else
    {
        [self setStringValue:@""];
    }
 }


 - (instancetype)initWithFrame:(NSrect)frame
 {
     if(self = [super initWithFrame:frame])
     {
         [self setEditable:NO];
         [self setSelectable:NO];
         [self setDrawsBackGround:NO];
         [self setBezeled:NO];
     }
     return self;
 }
 @end
```

Calling code:

```
XTextField* myLabel = [[XTextField alloc]initWithFrame:myFrame];
[myLabel settext:@"text text text"];
[myLabel setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail];
```

Comment: did you check your outlet for textfield...and post some code

Comment: @EICaptain I don't have outlets it is programmatically made NSTextFieldSubClass

Comment: @EICaptain I posted the code line where crashes what else code to post ?
`NSTextFieldSubClass` is a simple subclass that only renames a method `setStringValue` to `setText`

Comment: could you edit your question to show how you declare your "`NSTextFieldSubClass`" (e.g. the contents of the .h file and/or what the "`@interface`" looks like).  Also, subclasses should ***NEVER*** start with "`NS`", as that might confuse other people looking at your code into thinking it's an Apple-supplied class from the iOS SDK.

Comment: @MichaelDautermann Sure, just a sec. (P.S. it doesn't start with "`NS`" I renamed it here for the readable reasons to show that it is a Subclass Of `NSTextField`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots of questions that need to be answered here.  The problem, as indicated by the error message, is that the `setLineBreakMode:` selector was sent to an object that doesn't recognize that selector.  What could be happening that would cause that?  Figuring things like this out requires critical thinking and detective work.  Here are some ideas.

1. `-setLineBreakMode:` does not seem to actually be implemented by `NSTextField`; it is a method of `NSCell`, and of `NSMutableParagraphStyle`, as far as I can tell.  If you have an `NSTextField` (or a subclass of it) you'd normally call `[[myTextField cell] setLineBreakMode:...]`, but your code snippet doesn't indicate that you are doing that.  So unless you implemented this method in your subclass – which you don't state that you did – this is probably the reason for the crash.  Perhaps you don't see the crash on your Mac because this code path doesn't get hit, for whatever reason?  Or perhaps Apple privately implemented this method in Yosemite but not in Mavericks?  Who knows.  Do you get a warning from the compiler on that line, saying that the object does not respond to that selector?  Do not ignore compiler warnings.
2. The code you posted looks like you are calling `setLineBreakMode:` on the class object, not on an instance of the class; normally classes start with a capital letter, whereas instances start with a lowercase letter.  Obeying coding conventions like this makes things much less confusing for everybody.  And if your subclass is really named `NSTextFieldSubClass`, then I agree with @MichaelDautermann that you should never, ever name classes with an `NS` prefix; that is both confusing and asking for trouble, since for all you know Apple has a private subclass with exactly that name.  Class names beginning with `NS` are reserved by Apple.
3. It could be that the object you think is in the variable that you have apparently named `NSTextFieldSubClass` is not an instance of your subclass at all, or has been freed (and perhaps replaced by a new object at the same address), or some such problem, and that that is why it doesn't respond to the selector.  You could investigate this by turning on `NSZombieEnabled`, examining it in the debugger, adding an `NSLog` of it (perhaps with an added `-description` method in your subclass), or many other techniques.

That's all pretty vague, but then the question is vague.  You need to post the code for your subclass, the code where you instantiate the subclass, and the code surrounding the line that crashes, at a minimum, to get more specific help.  We can't read your mind, and the root of the bug may well be in one of those places.

Comment: I updated my question with actual code. Seems like you are right about the `cell` I will try that.

Comment: I didn't implement the `setLineBreakingMode` method but I think I will just implement it in my subclass (which is not starting with NS) this method and I guess it's implementation should be just `[self.cell setLineBreakMode:mode];`

Comment: Thank you for your answer sir!

Comment: The confusion was because: when I was typing `[myLabel setLine..]`
Xcode autocompleted it so I thought it is legit method of the `NSTextField` but I reviewed documentation of the `NSTextField` and there is no such method -- Also no warnings were shown

Comment: I'm surprised you didn't get a warning, and that Xcode autocompleted it for you.  If a variable is of type `id` then anything goes – any selector is considered acceptable, broadly speaking.  But if a variable has a specific type, as yours apparently does, then normally selectors get type-checked by both Xcode's completion and by the compiler.  There might be a warning setting for this that you need to turn on to get the warning, but I thought this particular warning was automatic.  Hmm.  Is the calling code in a file that has a `#import "XTextField.h"`?

Comment: Yes the file has an `#import "XTextField.h"`  Also the Xcode settings are default I never messed with them not to mention I just acquired a fresh copy of Xcode 7.01, which broke in update so i had to completely remove the old Xcode 7 and download 7.01 as a fresh copy of Xcode - Never touched the flags compiler warnings and non of those build settings

Comment: Also yes as you may see - in `init` method i returning as `instancetype` which i believe is `XTextField*` :-/

Comment: Well, odd.  The question of why you're not getting proper warnings for calling undeclared selectors, and proper type-based selector completion, might be a new stackoverflow question (if that question doesn't already exist).  Getting proper warnings/completion is important, as this question illustrates.  Anyhow, good luck, glad the present issue is resolved.

Comment: Yes you are right, there might be even more issues like that... And I will not know... Btw compiler does warn me on missing selectors...
It was only 2 like this now: 1) I mistakenly setViewController to NSWindow (Because that what I normally do in iOS) and compiler didn't warn + autocompleted this and now the NSTexrField...

Comment: Well when I added the method to my subclass Xcode kindly autocompleted it... :)